# Проблема с именем класса начинающимся на "Int"

Tags: php, классы, функции

Решили на серваке обновить php до версии 5.6 (с 5.3) - повалились ошибки:

> Catchable fatal error:  Argument X passed ... must be integer, object given in ...

На локальной виндовой машине таких ошибок не было. 
Тестовым путём было выявлено, что проблема в названии класса. Если он начинается на "Int...", например Inter, то интерпретатор ожидал тип Int в параметре функции.
Вообщем, следущий код:

```
<?php 
class Inter
{    
}

function foo(Inter $p)
{        
}

$a = new Inter();
foo($a);

echo 1;
?>
```

Генерит ошибку

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to foo must be integer, object given in /.../test.php on line 6

Если класс назвать Stringer, соотвественно получаем

> Argument 1 passed to foo must be string, object given

Если имя другое, то ошибки нет, но переименовывать названия классов в проекте не решение.

Comment: mod_fcgid - это к апачу относится.........апач какой у вас? надо 2.4...... пхп тут не причем абсолютно ........как доказательство можете зайти на http://phpfiddle.org/ и вбить `class Inter
{    
}

function foo(Inter $p)
{        
}

$a = new Inter();
foo($a);

echo 1;

phpinfo();` ......всё работает

Comment: У меня локально есть порядка 30 версий PHP от 5.0 до 7.1RC1 - во всех приведённый код работает корректно. При том, PHP5 вообще не умеет type hinting скалярных типов, это только в PHP7 сделали. А если намеренно указать ошибочный foo(int $p) - то ошибка будет немного другая "Argument 1 passed to foo() must be an instance of Int, instance of Inter given, called in". Именно "instance of тип". А в PHP7 - Uncaught TypeError весьма примечателен, т.е. тоже не то. Может, у вас установлен какой-то модуль нестандартный статической проверки типов?

Comment: @Мелкий не морочьте голову.. Объекты(имена классов) можно давать как тип и в 5-ой версии..... в php7 лишь добавились еще некоторые значения которые можно ставить